# Add SQL Server 2017 Reporting Service into SQL Cluster

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a cluster two node SQL Server 2017 Database installed, I would like to add-on Reporting Services, but unlike in 2016, I would have an option to install RS as an add-on, but since now the RS installer is a standalone one, how do I install and configure it in the SQL Cluster server? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried installing SSRS on all servers in your cluster. Configure a new role (generic service) in your failover cluster?

You can cluster any windows service in a failover cluster. You can also make them dependent on a different roles. Also read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/host-a-report-server-database-in-a-sql-server-failover-cluster)

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts I have not try this yet, i will try it. Thanks for the suggestion.